# Приложение-синглтон

Tags: java

Как сделать так, чтобы java-приложение могло быть запущенным одновременно только в одном экземпляре?
Искать наличие в процессах по определённому имени как-то не хочется, а вариант с созданием/записи в файл-"маркер" также не прокатит, тк такой вариант не крешеустойчив (т.е. должен быть предусмотрен вариант, что после аварийного завершения работы приложения оно сможет запуститься не выкидывая ошибку о том, что оно уже запущено).

Answer (score 1):

Смотрите в сторону PID-файлов. Записывайте в него PID процесса при старте, предварительно проверив наличие PID-файла и пинганув процесса, послав на него SIG_DFL, если PID-файл существует. Если ответ от SIG_DFL не придет, значит приложение рухнуло, а PID-файл остался, удаляем его и стартуем приложение... В общем я так демонов писал... Вот, почитай код [здесь](https://github.com/shamanis/daemon-php/blob/master/daemon.php) - обрати внимание на функцию getPID(), как это переделать на Java уже твоя забота :) Для сравнения, то же самое, [но на Python](https://github.com/shamanis/python-daemon/blob/master/daemon.py) так же погляди на get_pid().

Comment: PID могут повторно использоваться. Если приложение рухнуло, а был создан другой процесс с тем же PID, то приложение не будет стартовать, хотя должно. (Например, если падения была перезагружена система, а файл остался.)

Comment: Ну за 2 года использования этого подхода у меня ни разу не было такой ситуации, что было запущено другое приложение с тем же PID. Но даже в этом случае Вы можете посылать какой-то другой сигнал и ждать определенный ответ от приложения, но тогда в нем нужно делать обработчик сигналов. Почитайте про сигналы в общем.

Answer (score 0):

[Java Single Application Instance](http://www.rbgrn.net/content/43-java-single-application-instance).

Comment: Эмм... А что если другое приложение уже заняло выбранный порт?

Comment: Можно виндовый семафор использовать через JNI (он межпроцессный). И поискать аналог на linux платформах.

Answer (score -1):

Можно сделать так:

сделать конструктор приватным, а получать экземпляр в статическом методе, в котором будет проверяться был ли создан данных объект или нет (Если да то возвращать имеющийся, если нет то создать новый)

Например:

```
public class Sngltn {

private static Sngltn sngltn= null;

private Sngltn(){
}

public static Sngltn getSngltn(){
    if (sngltn == null) sngltn = new Sngltn();
    return sngltn;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Sngltn mySngltn = Sngltn.getSngltn();
}
```

}

Comment: ну и что?)

Comment: мдя, немного перепутал задание, но все равно, тогда можно добавить проверку если уже есть такой объект в системе (в статической переменной не null) тогда выйти из приложения. и все